# Ubuntu 11.10 monitor suspend glitch help?

Tags: 11.10, graphics, monitor, suspend

my monitor gets extremely glitchy after waking it from suspending it is there any fix to this problem?

here is a picture of the issue this is right after i wake it from it being suspended.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are being "helped" by the Power Manager, which runs when you enter or leave Suspend or Hibernate. Run `dpkg -L pm-utils` to see the files in the Power Manager package. `pm-utils` has a bunch of files dedicated to "video quirks". Maybe your monitor is listed, maybe you'll get to add it. Since I don't know what kind of monitor you have, I can't say.

When you suspend, the monitor's video signal goes away when your video card is powered off (does the monitor power off, too?) . I guess the picture is a mismatch between what your monitor expects to see when the video signal comes back, and what your video card sends.

What do you have to do to fix the display? Cycle power on it?